# django : passing form data between views

Tags: python, django, django-forms, httpwebrequest, django-views

I have a view :

```
class SomeView(FormView):
    form_class = SomeForm
    template_name = 'app/template.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class
        return render(request, self.template_name, {form:'form'})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_Valid():
        #do something here
        return HttpResponseRedirect("Go somewhere from here after processing")
```

In the `post` I need to make an API call which takes data from this form. Instead of this though, I want to redirect user to another view, where he can view all the data from the form and say `confirm`

On submit of this `confirm` view I should actually make this API call.

How do I pass the form data to another view ? I can simply store the form data in a dict and pass it on from the URL, but that might expose some crucial data at the browser level.

Is there a safer way to do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a litle helper from django:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/formtools/form-preview/